# Would a propeller underwater have thrust?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The type I mean is the ones on aircraft. Do the same physics apply with a propeller underwater?

Comment: Most definitely. It's how most ships are propelled. [See this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propeller#Propeller_theory).

Comment: I'm intrigued: why would you think otherwise?  Both air and water are fluids with nonzero coefficients of friction.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but not as efficiently as the screw propellers that are specifically designed to work in the more viscous fluid at lower speed. Aircraft propellers are specifically designed to operate at a higher speed in gas.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Second the question. The answer is accurate. Why the downvote and no explanation?

Comment: Don't know if it matters (or perhaps, how it matters), but water is not only more viscous, but also more dense, and *much* less compressible.